# Sencha Touch 2 link UI element which can be clicked

Tags: sencha-touch

See attachment, I want the "Forgot password" to be a link instead of a button, but I cant find any Link UI element in Sencha which listen for the click event, doesnt it exist?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sencha routes, e.g.:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        routes: {
            'forgot-password': 'forgotPassword'
        }
    },

    forgotPassword: function() {
        // Your code here
    }
});
```

Then you can formulate the link using the route name after a hashtag e.g.:

```
 http://myapp.com#forgot-password
```

More on routes here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/history_support

Comment: Smart, I liked this one! I actually sat the whole weekend implementing History support, so will fix do it like you describe

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use a component and define the html for it, please see the code below:

```
{
 xtype: 'component',
 html: '<a href='+'"http://abc.com"'+ '>Forgot your password?</a>',
}
```